# Tkinter option menu

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Hi there I am currently learning to use Tkinter in python 2.7. I am writing a programs that uses user accounts to select a different set of rules. In my program I am trying to make it so the user can click; "New User"or "Existing User." The problem is that I am using the tkinter the syntax for the optionmenu is as follows.

```
    option = OptionMenu(master, var, "one", "two", "three", "four")
    option.pack()
```

As seen the "One","two", and "three" are all options in the list, which I would like to replace with user names. The question is how do I take a mutable list of usernames, and input said list into this option field? I have tried using a tuple but to mo avail.. someone help me please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `*`-operator to unpack an argument list like so:

```
...
options = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
option = OptionMenu(master, var, *options)
option.pack()
...
```

More information about unpacking arguments can be found here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

You should note that the `*`-operator can also be used to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, for example:

```
def print_names(*names):
    for name in names:
        print(name)

print_names('Bob', 'James', 'Harry')
```

Which would output:

> ```
> Bob
> James
> Harry
> ```

There also exists the `**`-operator which works in a very similar way, except that it uses keyword arguments. If you wish to learn more about these operators and their usages, then I highly recommend visiting the documentation article that I linked above (relevant information begins here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).